# Using <td> instead of <tr> to show/hide a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am trying to use `<td class="t1 t4">Fixed</td>`rather than `<tr class="t1 t4">` in my code. This is because I may have many ways of filtering data, and it will just get messy. 
However how do I use this to filter the whole row, rather than just the cell?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#type :checkbox").click(function() {
    $("td").hide();
    $("#type :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
      $("." + $(this).val()).show();
    });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#fee :checkbox").click(function() {
    $("td").hide();
    $("#fee :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
      $("." + $(this).val()).show();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id="type">
  <p id="Mortgage Type">Mortgage Type</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t1" id="t1" />Fixed
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t2" id="t2" />Variable
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t3" id="t3" />Tracker
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t4" id="t4" checked/>All
  <br>
</section>

<section id="fee">
<p id="Fee">Fee</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="f1" id="f1" />Fee
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="f2" id="f2" />No Fee
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="f3" id="f3" checked/>All
  <br>
</section>

<div id="mortgagediv">
<table id="mortgagetable">
  <tr class="product">
    <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
    <td class="t1 t4">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1.64</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
    <td class="f1 f3"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">70</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">20,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="product">
    <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
    <td class="t2 t4">Variable</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1.69</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
    <td class="f1 f3"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">20,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="product">
    <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
    <td class="t3 t4">Tracker</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1.79</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
    <td class="f1 f3"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">20,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
<tr class="product">
    <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
    <td class="t1 t4">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1.64</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
    <td class="f2 f3"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">70</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">20,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="product">
    <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
    <td class="t2 t4">Variable</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1.69</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
    <td class="f2 f3"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">20,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="product">
    <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
    <td class="t3 t4">Tracker</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1.79</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
    <td class="f2 f3"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">20,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm confused by your question. If you're trying to hide a row, then you need to add `display: none` to the `<tr>` element. `<tr>` = Table Row.

Comment: I only want the row to hide when the checkbox for the `<td>` value is not selected?

Comment: Also, you only need one `$(document).ready()` function. Put all your code inside just one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean

```js
$(function() {
  $(":checkbox").on("click",function() {
    $(".product").hide();
    $(":checkbox:checked").each(function() {
      console.log($(this).val());
      $("." + $(this).val()).parent().toggle(1);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id="type">
  <p id="Mortgage Type">Mortgage Type</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t1" id="t1" />Fixed
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t2" id="t2" />Variable
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t3" id="t3" />Tracker
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t4" id="t4" checked/>All
  <br>
</section>

<section id="fee">
<p id="Fee">Fee</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="f1" id="f1" />Fee
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="f2" id="f2" />No Fee
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="f3" id="f3" checked/>All
  <br>
</section>

<div id="mortgagediv">
<table id="mortgagetable">
  <tr class="product">
    <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
    <td class="t1 t4">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1.64</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
    <td class="f1 f3"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">70</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">20,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="product">
    <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
    <td class="t2 t4">Variable</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1.69</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
    <td class="f1 f3"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">20,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="product">
    <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
    <td class="t3 t4">Tracker</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1.79</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
    <td class="f1 f3"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">20,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
<tr class="product">
    <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
    <td class="t1 t4">Fixed</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1.64</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
    <td class="f2 f3"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">70</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">20,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="product">
    <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
    <td class="t2 t4">Variable</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1.69</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
    <td class="f2 f3"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">20,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="product">
    <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
    <td class="t3 t4">Tracker</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1.79</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
    <td class="f2 f3"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">20,000</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: hen I choose an option from checkbox <section id="type"> e.g. 'tracker' it works fine. When I then choose from checkbox <section id="fee"> e.g. 'no fee', it then doesn't take into account the selection from the first checkbox and shows all results that should still be filtered by <section id="type">?

Comment: Try the new one. The logic in the code is ok, the logic in the cell class perhaps not. You need to uncheck all and check others